# Нет соединения с интернетом xubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu

Когда начал использовать Ubuntu, пробовал поставить xubuntu. Не сильно получилось, из xubuntu стал только экран при загрузке системы. Сейчас пытался настроить mysql, перезагрузить ПК и у меня стала полность xubuntu. Я был не против, но оказалось, что нет интернета, просто никакого намека на не, ни иконки, ни слова в настройках. Полез в Гугл пытался изменять строку grup, не вышло ничего. Кто можешь помочь? Буду благодарен! Всех с новым годом!

Comment: Если система изначально нормально не встала, то лучше переустановить прежде чем что-то дальше делать. Моё ИМХО.

Comment: При загрузке с live cd интернет есть?